# How to create a copy or backup of a database through JDBC Connection to store on local machine and connect via MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Is it possible to copy a database onto my local machine from a JDBC connection? The software this database is on will be terminated in a few months and I want to create a copy or backup of the database so I can access the data from MySQL Workbench.

Comment: You can't do this directly. You will need to use the normal MySQL backup and restore process (which you can call from Java if you really need to, see duplicate).

Comment: Is there a link on how to create a MySQL Backup using Java?

Comment: The duplicate link in the close reason block above your question shows a way.